# Need ios app for read and mark pdf documents

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf

I need some ios app for ipad where I can read scientific pdf documents and mark part of text and do some notes on the margin of the document and then read it with marks at my PC.

An option can be to get translate of selected word in small pop-up window near word.

What you can suggest?

Comment: I would definately suggest that you start searching in the AppStore for an app that can do this.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate. The linked question has a slightly broader scope but most PDF readers offer note capabilities by default. In case none of the tools there solve your problem, please edit your question to add which tools you have tried and which functionality you are still missing so we can reopen the question.